# How to filter null or empty value from Json string

Tags: c#, json

I have a one Model it's look like

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

and I tried to convert in Json request using below mentioned code.

```
var l=new List<Data>();
l.Add(new Data(){Name="foo",Address ="bar",ContactNo =123});
l.Add(new Data(){Name="biz",Address ="baz"});
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
```

it will give me string like

```
 [{"Name":"foo","Address":"bar","ContactNo":"123"},{"Name":"biz","Address":"baz","ContactNo":""}]
```

in output second ContactNo has a empty string but I don't need the field which has a no value or NULL .
can anyone please tell me what is the best way to avoid NULL or Empty field from Json request?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: a) What is `Data`? b) `ContactNo` can not be empty(or "123") string since it is `integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model as below

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

and then serialize your object as below

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
             l, 
             new JsonSerializerSettings() 
             { 
                 NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
             });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but when I tried string messageToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(api,converter, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }); it will give me error like Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'

Comment: Your are passing three arguments please check my answer again

Comment: Ya but I need second argument to convert datetime so can you please tell me how it's possible?

Comment: it ignores null values only. How to handle empty values??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Json.Net.

You can use the System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute. This allows you to mark a property to use a different default value than null.

So, if you want empty strings to be ignored in your JSON output you can update the model class to look like this:

```
public class DataClass
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling must be set to Ignore or IgnoreAndPopulate for this to be picked up.

A more thorough example of various approaches for reducing serialized json size is here:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size

Comment: Note: I am a little uncertain if you intended ContactNo to be an int instead of a string. The accepted answer is an int, but the question is edited. I assume this is a relevant answer since the question specifically asks for the empty string.

Comment: I know ;) But I originally arrived here from google, looking for the answer. Since others with the same question could end up here I went back to add the answer after I had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.You may add a flag in the model class.

```
public class DataClass{
public bool isIllegal{get;set;}
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string ContactNo { get; set{isIllegal=!string.isNullOrEmpty(value);)}
}
```

2.You can filter data whose isIllegal is false after JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l).

Comment: you mean I have to check each and every property with isIllegal? that is not a proper solution what if I have 25 property in model.